# How can i make a mongoDB subdocument have an unique id or incremented id?

Tags: json, database, mongodb

**Solved**

I am having this MongoDB document:

```
{
  _id: "5e3bf72db5074c1e205409f5",
  todos: [
  {
    title: "title",
    description: "description",
    state: "state",
    priority: "priority"
  }
],
  title: "test project"
}
```

and I want to keep the main '_id:' property for the project but also add an "_id:" or something of that sorts to my todos so that I can do CRUD operations on them alone easier. Is there a way of making a unique id or autoincremented id for them? The final result would look like this

Is there a way to do this? also, any other suggestions are appreciated.

```
{
  _id: another unique id or autoincrement key,
  title: "title",
  description: "description",
  state: "state",
  priority: "priority"
}
```

Comment: MongoDB doesn't by default add `_id`'s to subdocuments, But few drivers are capable of doing that, what programming language do you use ?

Comment: @whoami, i am using express js, what could i use?

Comment: while using mongoose schemas sub docs will have `_id`'s

Comment: @whoami this did the job I was looking for thank you!